# are automatic playlists possible?

Tags: mediaelement.js

is it possible to send a playlist to the mediaelements-player, that the player plays automatically all videos each after? 
Does this work in iOS?
What is, when the player gets 5 Playlists, can he show them as parallel Buttons?
best regards, urs

Comment: were you able to resolve this issue?